# Pipe output file into UNIX tool

Tags: unix, mutt, sox

I want to pipe the output file from the command line audio tool SoX into the email tool mutt.

What I want to do is something akin to this:

```
sox /Users/someUser/Desktop/input.mp3 output.mp3 | mutt -s "someSubject" -a [output-from-sox] some@recipient.com
```

The thing I don't know how to do is wrapped in square brackets.

I'm a UNIX novice so any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't mean `sox /Users/someUser/Desktop/input.mp3 output.mp3 ; mutt -s "someSubject" -a output.mp3 some@recipient.com` do you? You want to send the *command line output*?

Comment: I want sox to output the mp3-file and mutt to email that file. I don't know if my pipe approach is the right way to do this :S

Comment: Since your `sox` call writes `output.mp3`, why don't you just use that one like I suggested and delete it after sending? In case sending fails or something like that, you'll still have the file to try again.

Comment: Instead of using ; to separate the commands, use && so that the second command only runs if the first one was successful.

Comment: It's an Applescript that sends this line to the Terminal, so I would like to keep it in one line.

Comment: @Matt Cool, I'll look into that :)

Comment: What are you trying to do there with sox, recompress the mp3 file? (see http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)

Comment: It's worth to add that common practice is denoting stdin/stdout as single dash `-`, whenever input/output file arguments are considered. See example in [cat(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cat&sektion=1) manpage for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pipe in a Unix-like operating system is for running one program, taking its standard output (which would otherwise go to the screen) and using it as input to another program (in place of its standard input which would normally come from the keyboard).

It seems like what you want to do is have one program output *to a file*, and then have another program *use the file as input*. You don't need a pipe for that.

To run one program after another one finishes, all on one command line, use `;`. For example:

```
sox /Users/someUser/Desktop/input.mp3 output.mp3 ; mutt -s "someSubject" -a output.mp3 some@recipient.com
```

Unix command line programs output an "exit status" or "return code". Most programs output 0 to indicate that they did their thing successfully, or some other value if there was a problem. If your first command is like this, use `&&` in place of `;` to only run the second command if the first one was successful. For example:

```
sox /Users/someUser/Desktop/input.mp3 output.mp3 && mutt -s "someSubject" -a output.mp3 some@recipient.com
```

Comment: Really helpful explanation, thx a bunch! :)